# Add filtering parameters in drf_yasg Swagger in django-rest-framework Viewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I am using django-rest-framework Viewset and i have one list API in that i have to add filtering parameters **start_date** and **end_date** in request body in swagger.

```
class SchoolManagementView(ViewSet):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(**kwargs)
      self.payload = {}
      self.college_list_service = CollegeListService(view=self)

  @swagger_auto_schema(
      operation_description="Listing Inward Document",
      responses={status.HTTP_200_OK: "Success"}
    )
  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      self.payload = self.college_list_service.execute(request)
      return ResponseHandler.success(payload=self.payload)
```

**Note**: Here i am using all my filter backends in "college_list_service" file